# AngularJS ng-bind-html with a Variable in it

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I'm new to AngularJS. 
I have a HTML table like the following:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>other stuff</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="rule in rules">
    <td>@{{ rule.id }}</td>
    <td ng-init="functionThatExecutesHttpPost(rule.id)" ng-bind-html="variable"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The Angular Function looks like this:

```
$scope.functionThatExecutesHttpPost = function(ruleId) {
    $http.post('***'+ruleId).success(function(data) {
        $scope.variable = data;
    });
}
```

The problem that I'm now having is that the data I want to have in my HTML View is in every 'td' not only in the one with the right ID. After little thinking this is the behaviour you could expect. 


**My Question now is:**

Is it possible to give that 'ng-bind-html' a variable like --> variable(rule.id) and then in the Angular function I write something like --> $scope.variable(ruleId) = data;

Or is there maybe another aproach to this problem?


Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you don't `ng-include` then/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution would be load the template using `ng-include` directive if you don't want to perform any operation. It will load required template inside that td as you were doing it from ajax.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="rule in rules">
    <td>@{{ rule.id }}</td>
    <td ng-include="'******'+ rule.id"></td>
</tr>
```

The hardcoded URL remains in single quotes, and other dynamic `ng-repeat` current variable come as is by concatenated with `+` sign.